# Android Contact picture issue

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

I've got an issue with retrieving contact pictures. On my Galaxy Nexus (running JB, 4.1.1) when I get the contact pictures they show up REALLY small. When I run the same code on my Droid 2 (Runing GB, 2.3.7) I always get my default image.

Here's my code:

```
Cursor cursor;

    cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
            new String[]{id}, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex((ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)));

    pictureID = Uri.withAppendedPath(result, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY).toString();

    if(contactPicture(Uri.parse(pictureID)))
    {
        contactsEditor.putString(""+id+ "Picture", pictureID);
    }
    else
        contactsEditor.putString("" + id + "Picture", "" + R.drawable.ic_contact_picture);

    contactsEditor.commit();

    contactNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex((ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));

    cursor.close();
```

all of the variables/constants are properly defined (If you would like to see the definition, ask and I will post them)

and here's the xml I'm putting it into:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/contactPhotoDesc"
                android:id="@+id/contactPic"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/contactName"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/contactNumber"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My default image shows fine, but when I retrieve an image from a contact, it shows up really small on the GNex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the Galaxy Nexus is high resolution device, and the picture seems to be not, so (if not scaled) it will look smaller.

You can set the ImageView to a fixed size, instead of wrap_content, and it will scale up.

You also can use this method:

> public static InputStream openContactPhotoInputStream (ContentResolver cr, Uri contactUri, boolean preferHighres)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#openContactPhotoInputStream(android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.net.Uri,%20boolean)

It seems like it will return a high res contact picture (if available). You still need to set fixed size in the ImageView, anyways, since in low res devices, if Android still returns high res picture, it will look very big.

Comment: OK, that seems to have worked for the Galaxy Nexus, but I still have 2 questions:

1) can I set different sizes for the ImageView for different screen sizes
2) Why are the contact pictures not showing up on the Droid 2? It still always returns my default picture.

Comment: 1) yes, the best approach would be to use styles: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html 2) maybe it depends from the data stored in the device? I don't have experience retrieving contacts, but you could read for example http://app-solut.com/blog/2011/03/working-with-the-contactscontract-to-query-contacts-in-android/ or http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2009/12/30/handling-contact-photos-all-api-levels/